# three.js `shaderMaterial` looks odd in my code

Tags: three.js

I use `three.js` `shaderMaterial`made a example.But material looks very odd.When i rotate the camera `shaderMaterial` not move.[image][image]

Here is my code.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 2,2,2 );
            var shaderMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                uniforms:{
                    resolution:{value: new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight)}
                },
                vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
                fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
            });
            shaderMat.side = 2;
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, shaderMat );
            scene.add( mesh );
```

and GLSL code

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
        varying vec2 vUv;
        void main() {
            vec2 vUv = uv;
            vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader" >
        precision mediump float;
        uniform vec2 resolution;
        varying vec2 vUv;
        void main(void) {
            vec2 q = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
            vec2 p = -1.0 + 2.0 * q;

            float v = p.x;
            vec3 col = vec3(0.01 * max(0.0, 1.0), 0.1 * max(0.0, p.x), 0.0) / abs(v * 2.0);
            float op = 0.01/abs(v * 2.0);
            gl_FragColor = vec4(col, op);
        }
    </script>
```

I do not know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: What do you expect? `v = p.x;` is in range  [-1.0, 1.0]. So `0.01/abs(v * 2.0);` is equal to 1.0 if `abs(v) == 0.005`. If `abs(v) >= 0.005` it rapidly goes down and the alpha channel goes to 0.

Comment: Looks a lot like you are trying to convert a shader that works on a 2d canvas (shadertoy?) to a shader for a 3d object. Maybe you want to be using `uVu.xv` rather than `resolution.xy` ? Did you write the shader code of copy it from somewhere?

Comment: Please define `looks odd`. This looks perfectly normal to me. You have a shader, it's transforming some vertices, and painting some pixels.

Comment: `convert a shader that works on a 2d canvas to a shader for a 3d object` that is what i want. I copy this code from `codepen`,and use it to `shaderMaterial`.But the position of the red part not move with camera,it is always In the middle of the browser screen. It looks not like a 3D material.@Rabbid76 @2pha @pailhead

Comment: Seems you need to study up a bit more on how shaders work. Maybe [THIS EXAMPLE](https://2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/simple_faded_lines.html) could help.

Comment: and HERE is a [good youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLW3Zl3wyJwWMpFSRpeMmSBGDShbkiV1Cq) I found a while back. And [HERE are my own experiments](https://2pha.com/blog/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial/) when I started learning shaders

Comment: Thanks for your example,thank you very much@2pha